# «НЕ КУПАНИЕМ В ВАННЕ И МАНИКЮРОМ ЕДИНЫМ (И)»

Tags: согласование

Предложение: «НЕ КУПАНИЕМ В ВАННЕ И МАНИКЮРОМ ЕДИНЫМ (И)». Склоняюсь к тому, что согласование всё-таки в единственном числе, по последнему «маникюру».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Не купанием в ванной и маникюром единым...***

Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится **в форме единственного числа:** 1) если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к остальным,  например: каждый завод и фабрика; уличный шум и грохот; морской прилив и отлив;

В приведенном примере определение находится в постпозиции, но явно относится к обоим существительным и сочетается с ближайшим словом.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_05)